# jcifs.smb.SmbException: 0xC0000205

Tags: java, jcifs

I am using jcifs to copy the network files. But while copying the files i am getting the following exception. I searched about this, but i didn't see any proper solution.

**Exception :**

```
Caused by: jcifs.smb.SmbException: 0xC0000205
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:614)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:713)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:550)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:764)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:781)
at jcifs.smb.SmbRandomAccessFile.<init>(SmbRandomAccessFile.java:57)
```

Answer (score 2):

For future googlers, from [this post](https://lists.samba.org/archive/jcifs/2012-June/009954.html),

```
NT STATUS code 0xC0000205 is:
Insufficient server memory to perform the requested operation
```

This wasn't much help to me, but when I tried again it went away (and I got a different exception). Good luck.